# Can I remove YouTube recommendations on full screen display of embedded video?

Tags: url-parameters, youtube, embedded-control

When loading a YouTube video full screen via the following arguments:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&version=3&vq=hd1080
```

It unfortunately shows a ribbon of recommendations at the bottom when you pause the video:
[image: example recommendation ribbon]

And it shows these recommendations when the video ends:
[image: examples at end]

Is there a way to eliminate these?

Comment: YouTube embedded player parameter documentation is here:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters   Have you tried the `rel` parameter?   It looks like it will work for the ones at the end, it doesn't say anything about when they are paused though, so I'm not sure if it would help there.